# NSTableView in NSDrawer issue

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

Currently i am developing a app with a borderless window and a NSDrawer within the borderless window,and there is a NSTableView in the drawer.
Problem is when i select a row in the table,and then click the miniaturize button i create manually in the borderless window,it's useless,nothing happens.but when i close the drawer,the miniaturize button works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try sending `-close:` to the drawer before miniaturizing the window.

Comment: Hey,thanks for reply,i do some research,also i've try send -close to the drawer before miniaturizing the window,but not work.Seems that its caused by the traffic light button i add to the window manually.Here is some of my code. I will attach some code below.

Comment: - (void)setContentView:(NSView *)aView{[super setContentView:aView];minButton = [NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowMiniaturizeButton forStyleMask:NSTitledWindowMask];
 NSRect minButtonRect = [minButton frame];
 [minButton setFrame:NSMakeRect(WINDOW_FRAME_PADDING -2, bounds.size.height - (WINDOW_FRAME_PADDING - 20) - minButtonRect.size.height, minButtonRect.size.width, minButtonRect.size.height)];
 [minButton setAutoresizingMask:NSViewMaxXMargin | NSViewMinYMargin];
 [aView addSubview:minButton];} i have no idea if this is the right approach.